# Classifier in tensowflow returning error from size of labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network

I have a database consisting of two columns, and I want to use the first one to obtain the second one. The first one has roughly 3000 elements, and the second one has exactly 151 elements. to do this, I generated a dense neural network in tensorflow. However, I am obtaining a strange error during the training.

Here is the code I produced

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_excel('nn.xlsx')
x_data = df.drop('NCM',axis=1)

lista = df['NCM'].values.tolist()
prods = df['PRODUTO'].values.tolist()

seen = set()
ncm = [x for x in lista if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]

seen = set()
prods = [x for x in prods if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]

assigned = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('PRODUTO',prods)
feat_cols = [assigned]
labels = df['NCM']  
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_data, labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=101)
input_func =         tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_train,y=y_train,batch_size=10,num_epochs=1000,shuffle=True)

input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_train,y=y_train,batch_size=10,num_epochs=1000,shuffle=True)
embedded_group_col = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(assigned,dimension=len(prods))

feat_cols = [embedded_group_col]

dnn_model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units = [10,10,10],feature_columns=feat_cols,n_classes=len(ncm))
dnn_model.train(input_fn=input_func,steps = 1000)
```

And the code runs fine until the last line, in which it gives the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): assertion failed: [Labels must <= n_classes - 1] [Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:x (dnn/head/labels:0) = ] [[22030000][22030000][22030000]...] [y (dnn/head/assert_range/Const:0) = ] [151]
```

Which is very strange, since I have guaranteed that the number of classes is exactly the same as len(ncm).

What can be causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not enough to make the number of classes the same as `len(ncm)`. You must ensure that the target label ids (`y_train`, `y_test`) only contain integers from 0 to 150 (since your number of classes is 151).

You might want to do something similar as your feature - use a categorical feature transformer to map whatever label ids into integers between 0 and 150 (inclusive).

For example, you could try below:

```
mapping_strings = tf.constant(['904060','21069090',...,'99998771'])
table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor(
    mapping=mapping_strings, num_oov_buckets=0)
label_ids = table.lookup(labels)
```

Note that after your classifier is learned, to decode the class ids into your class strings (a reverse mapping), you can use [`tf.contrib.lookup.index_to_string_table_from_tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup/index_to_string_table_from_tensor).

Comment: Thank you, I am committing an error. I have 151 classes, but their labels are not [0,1,2,...,150]; instead, their labels are some numbers in code, like ['904060','21069090',...,'99998771']. Is there an easy way to deal with this with tensorflow/pandas?

Comment: add an example for transforming the label string into ids with `index_table_from_tensor`. You could also try `index_table_from_file`.